# Paypal checkout return data

Tags: paypal

I have a paypal button as follows:

```
<form id="fmPaypal" method="post" action= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="NZD">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="blah01@yahoo.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order">
        <input type="hidden" id="item_number" name="item_number" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.blah.com/checkout/return.cfm" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.blah.com/checkout/cancel" />
</form>
```

This works and users are redirected to paypal ready for payment.

But, should I expect to get some data returned from paypal via the return URL? e.g. results of the transaction? Or should I assume that the payment processed successfully if the user is redirected to the return url?

Tried getting this information from the docs without success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B

You have to enable the rm option on your form while you want to use return url

> - return(Optional) The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser
>   after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your
>   site that displays a "Thank you for your payment" page.  Default –
>   PayPal redirects the browser to a PayPal webpage. 1,024
> - rm:  (Optional)  Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the
>   URL specified by the return variable. Allowable values are:
>
> 0 – all shopping cart payments use the GET method
>
> 1 – the buyer's
> browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but
> no payment variables are included
>
> 2 – the buyer's browser is
> redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment
> variables are included The default is 0.
>
> Note: The rm variable takes effect only if the return variable is set.

Here is reference document what IPN return

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Then I quoted it here for convenient review

> $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
> $item_number =  $_POST['item_number'];
> $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
> $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
> $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
> $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
> $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
> $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

you should have this document PDF already, but I think I should put  it here also
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf

Of cause I have to remind about the important thing, you have to enable "Auto Return" on your account

> Auto Return is turned off by default. To turn on Auto Return:
>
> Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com. The My
> Account Overview page appears. Click the Profile subtab. The Profile
> Summary page appears. Click the My Selling Tools link in the left
> column. Under the Selling Online section, click the Update link in the
> row for Website Preferences. The Website Payment Preferences page
> appears Under Auto Return for Website Payments, click the On radio
> button to enable Auto Return. In the Return URL field, enter the URL
> to which you want your payers redirected after they complete their
> payments. NOTE: PayPal checks the Return URL that you enter. If the
> URL is not properly formatted or cannot be validated, PayPal will not
> activate Auto Return. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click the
> Save button.

Comment: That is just awesome! Thank you so much my friend.

Comment: @Telvin would you please have a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758114/adjust-form-and-return-url-to-get-all-desired-variabled-from-paypal

Answer (score 2):

The user will complete or cancel the payment on the PayPal platform and is redirected back to your website;

they complete the payment either when the user is redirected back or via an Instant Payment Notification (IPN).