# The correct way to get variables sent by PayPal to the return URL

Tags: paypal, return-value

I'm following the steps from this answer [Paypal checkout return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007480/paypal-checkout-return-data#answers) to redirect buyers automatically to the return URL like this (as you can see the rm option is set to 2)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="U74VBC2YUQS7E">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="subscribe">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="RETURN URL FOR CONFIRMED PAYMENTS">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
 <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

now I'm trying to set Auto Return in paypal account to redirect the buyer automatically to the return URL but there's no "Website Payment Preferences" option.

[image]

Second question: how to send custom variables and fetch them again using the return url like username, password..... any data entered by the user before paying so I can grab all the data like this

```
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_status= $_POST['payment_status'];
```

so if the status is Completed and the returned amount is equal to the form amount I can use the returned email, username and password to create a paid account on my site

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

My idea is to use custom field like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="user=username&password=encrypted-user-pass-with-sha1">
```

but I guess it's wrong as mentioned here [amount of non-hosted paypal buy now buttin is not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756207/amount-of-non-hosted-paypal-buy-now-buttin-is-not-changing#answers)

Sorry for this long post and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Manage Buttons. It's set on the button, not the account, or you can set it yourself in the form.